# How to add subdomain with canonical name through domain connect protocol (domainconnect.org)

Tags: dns, subdomain

I can't add subdomain with canonical name through [domainconnect.org](https://domainconnect.org) API.
I'm using [ext-domain-connect](https://github.com/gaalferov/ext-domain-connect) project. The all exist examples are about adding A records.

How I can add subdomain with canonical name through domain connect protocol?

Example of adding A records from [ext-domain-connect](https://github.com/gaalferov/ext-domain-connect)

```
try {
    $applyUrl = (new TemplateService())->getTemplateSyncUrl(
        'www.example-domain.com',
        'exampleservice.domainconnect.org',
        'template1',
        [
            'IP' => '132.148.25.185',
            'RANDOMTEXT' => 'shm:1531371203:Hello world sync',
        ],
        $privateKey,
        $keyId
    );
    print_r($applyUrl);
} catch (DomainConnectException $e) {
    echo (sprintf('An error has occurred: %s', $e->getMessage()));
}
```